# .htaccess rewrite from one subdirectory to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file:

`/forums/faq.php` -- at http://www.domain.com/forums/faq.php

I would like calls to this file (which are usually done in the form of faq.php?faq=faqname) to be rewritten as:

`/faq/faqname` -- at http://www.domain.com/faq/faqname

I've been trying the following .htaccess rules to no avail.  On my root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/faq.php?faq=(.*)$ faq/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^faq$ faq/ [L,QSA,R=301]
```

On my /forums/.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^faq.php?faq=(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/faq/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Could I be overlooking something really obvious here?  Is my syntax off?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can ditch the rules in the `/forums/` htaccess, the rules there have precedence over rules in the document root. You don't need them in both places.
2. Your rules will cause a redirect loop if they did what you wanted.

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, so the first rule won't match anything. What you really want to do is match against the actual request.

```
# redirect /forums/faq.php?faq=faqname to /faq/faqname
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /forums/faq\.php\?faq=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^forums/faq.php$ /faq/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Then you need to internally change it back

```
RewriteRule ^faq/(.+)$ /forums/faq.php?faq=$1 [L,QSA]
```